# How to add a 'CHECK EXISTS' constraint to a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm fairly new to SQL/PSQL, and am familiar so far with adding a constraint to a table that checks that there NOT EXISTS a certain condition. This makes sense to me, as each time a new row is added, it can check whether that row breaks the condition, and continue if it doesn't.

But how would I add a constraint to a table to check that there EXISTS a row that satisfies a condition? At the moment, when the first row is inserted (which doesn't satisfy the condition, but a later one may do) it fails as the condition is not met.

How do I implement this correctly?

I tried writing it exactly like a CHECK NOT EXISTS constraint, but without the NOT. This resulted in the above issue, and I understand why.

A basic idea of what I've tried so far, and is conceptually what I want to work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CheckSomeLargeAttendance()
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN(
      EXISTS(
      SELECT 1
      FROM event e
      WHERE e.attending > 100
      )
    );
END;
$$ language plpgsql;

ALTER TABLE event
ADD CONSTRAINT SomeLargeAttendance CHECK(
  CheckSomeLargeAttendance()
);
```

I.e. I want to check that, when all data is added to the table, there is at least one event with an attendance of more than 100.

Comment: You can't really express something like that as a constraint. In theory this is what "assertions" in the SQL standard are intended for, but no DBMS supports them.

Comment: That's an illegal use of check constraints, and it is going to break your database, like I told you.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If assertions are not supported, what can I do instead?

Comment: Using a set of triggers

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is unsupported, and it will lead to trouble. [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) says:

> PostgreSQL does not support `CHECK` constraints that reference table data other than the new or updated row being checked. While a CHECK constraint that violates this rule may appear to work in simple tests, it cannot guarantee that the database will not reach a state in which the constraint condition is false (due to subsequent changes of the other row(s) involved). This would cause a database dump and restore to fail. The restore could fail even when the complete database state is consistent with the constraint, due to rows not being loaded in an order that will satisfy the constraint. If possible, use `UNIQUE`, `EXCLUDE`, or `FOREIGN KEY` constraints to express cross-row and cross-table restrictions.

If you dig around in the mailing list archives, you will find reports of such failures, for example [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/20091001135900.GE25444%40a-kretschmer.de) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/MW3PR19MB425266FADCD7289F6BC8EC82A4FC0%40MW3PR19MB4252.namprd19.prod.outlook.com).

You could have such a check with a statement level trigger (but don't add the trigger before you insert the first row):

```
CREATE FUNCTION has_big_event() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM event WHERE attending > 100)
   THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'the table does not contain a big enough event';
   END IF;

   RETURN NULL;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER has_big_event BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON event
   FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION has_big_event();
```

Comment: Thank you for your responses, what can I do instead to try and achieve the same outcome without using a CHECK constraint?

Comment: Is that really what you want to achieve? Then you wouldn't be able to add the first row to the table, because it doesn't yet contain a row that matches the condition. If you come up with a realistic scenario, I'll try to show how that could be done.

Comment: The scenario I'd like to work would be to check that at least one row satisfies the above condition, after all the rows have been inserted to the table.

Comment: @user20678342 How does it know when all rows have been inserted?  Are they all inserted in a single transaction?